# Subquery return value but my query zero rows

Tags: mysql

I have table t1 and t2 in t1 have not records but t2 have rows.

Table script is

```
create table t1 ( n1 integer,n3 integer,n4 integer);

create table t2 (n2 integer);

insert into t2 value(1);

select n1,t22.n2 from t1 ,(select n2 from t2) t22;
null

select n2 from t2;
10
```

I should get the values

```
select n1,n3,n4,t22.n2 from t1 ,(select n2 from t2) t22;

output :- 0,0,0,10
```

Comment: You appear to be selecting a row from t1 and then using a sub query to get a value from t2 for the selected row from t1. However if t1 has no data (as you say) then no rows will be returned.

Comment: You should have at least one row in your t1 table for Cartesian product to be not empty

Answer (score 0):

What you appear to want is the values returned from t2, whether there is a (matching?) row on t1 or not.

If so this will do it:-

```
SELECT t1.n1, t1.n3, t1.n4, t22.n2 
FROM (SELECT n2 FROM t2) t22
LEFT OUTER JOIN t1;
```

However if you want items from t1 if there is no matching row from t2, and also any items from t2 if there is no matching row from t1 then this would normally need a full outer join. MySQL does not support full outer joins, but you can emulate them with 2 LEFT JOINs and UNIONing the results together.

Something like this:-

```
SELECT t1.n1, t1.n3, t1.n4, t22.n2 
FROM (SELECT n2 FROM t2) t22
LEFT OUTER JOIN t1
UNION 
SELECT t1.n1, t1.n3, t1.n4, t22.n2 
FROM t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT n2 FROM t2) t22;
```